# Calculating the amount based on the dropdown selected option using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the demo link https://jsfiddle.net/harshithanaidu1991/sk07p4fj/2/

I am getting the values from hidden inputs by using ID's of those Inputs as follows `subtA,servicetax,sbc,kkc,wht,subtotalD`.
I have two dropdowns called as `basis and division` and `division` will come only when the `value of basis` equals to `Others`.

1. if the value of basis equals to 'equal' , the amount which i am getting from the hidden inputs has to divided by 5 that means equally sharing among div1 to div5.
2. if the values of `basis` equals to `between 1 to 3` , the amount will be shared between div1 to div3.
3. if the value of `basis` equals to `specific` then `division` dropdown will come , based on the selctiong of division dropdown amount will be shared accordingly to that particular division.
4. if the value of `basis` equals to `others` , whatever the amount will be entered in the inputs from div1 to div5 the first row will be shared accordingly by calculating the percentage with `subtA`  and i am applying that percentage to remaining inputs.

As soon as i select `others` from `basis dropdown`, `NaN` values are coming in inputs even when i am using `parseFloat` how to avoid this and how to validate like the sum of amount entered in the inputs(only first row of the table) should not be more than `subtA` .?

And please suggest me if there is any other way to do in an easier way without writing so much code if every if condition ??

Answer (score 0):

Do parseFloat when grab value into variable instead of after mathematical operation.

```
var basis = parseFloat($('#basis').val());
var subtA = parseFloat($('#subtA').val());
var othertax = parseFloat($('#othertax').val());
var subtB = parseFloat($('#subtB').val());
var servicetax = parseFloat($('#servicetax').val());
var sbc = parseFloat($('#sbc').val());
var kkc = parseFloat($('#kkc').val());
var subtC = parseFloat($('#subtC').val());
var subtD = parseFloat($('#subtD').val());
var wht = parseFloat($('#wht').val());
var rate = parseFloat($('#rate').val());
var division = parseFloat($('#division').val());
```

Comment: i added still its giving NaN values ..@Haresh Vidja